# why babel is not converted es6 to es5 using webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, babel-loader

I am trying to convert my es6 syntax ( import and export keyword , arrow function) files in es5 using babel in moduler bundler webpack . I am able to do that but in bundle I saw few `arrow function` why ? is babel not able to compile those ?

I do like this

**webpackconfig.js**

```
 module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
```

`.babelrc`

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]
}
```

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.16",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.15",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.5",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-alpha.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^7.1.2",
```

but I got bundle which started from `arrow function`.
`bundle.js`

```
 (() => {
        "use strict";
        var t, e, a, n, u = (t = function () {
        enter code here
          ({
            init: function () {
                this.initComponents()
            }, initComponents: function () {
                Ut.init(), Pt.init()
            }
        }).init()
    })();
```

Comment: Where have you told it to target es5?

Answer (score 3):

The arrow function you have seen is generated by `webpack` which is not from `babel` at all. Basically `webpack` allows you configure to fully support `es5` syntax by setting up [`target`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/#target).

Here's an example:

```js
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
   // ...
  target: ['web', 'es5'],
}
```

Alternatively, if you wish to use `browserslist`, you can simply set as `browserslist` and provide the configuration via `package.json`

```js
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
   // ...
  target: ['browserslist'],
}
```

And specify the configuration:

```js
// package.json
{
  // ...
  "browserslist": [
    "IE 11"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I tried `"browserslist": [
    "IE 11"
  ]` in package.json than it removes

Comment: Yeah that's right I also updated the answer reflecting for the `browserlist` case